# How to run "hipster" pure Java program in Android Studio, specifically?

Tags: java, android, dijkstra

I am going to develop indoor navigation app using Android studio using this "Hipster" library.Hipster provide several Algorithms for searching and shortest path calculations.in my case it is Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm.

in Hipster, They have mention, "This is pure Java library".
I use this library in Eclipse and it's working fine.

my question is,

I am newbie to Android and Android Studio i tried to implement this code in Android Studio as well but it seems not working. I used provided sample by the library authors.

and I used this Gradle dependency:

```
 implementation 'es.usc.citius.hipster:hipster-core:1.0.1'
```

Official Web - http://www.hipster4j.org/
Github       - https://github.com/citiususc/hipster

I used this example:

https://github.com/citiususc/hipster/blob/1.0.X/hipster-examples/src/main/java/es/usc/citius/hipster/examples/UndirectedGraphSearchExample.java

I put this line to show result on my android app instead to System.out.print.

```
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search('L'),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but this line is highlighted and when i hover mouse pointer, Android Studio says

```
 Cannot resolve method 'makeText(android.content.Context, es.usc.citius.hipster.algorithm.Algorithm.SearchResult, int)
```

Here this is my MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.ireshan.indoor_navigation;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;

 import es.usc.citius.hipster.algorithm.Hipster;
 import es.usc.citius.hipster.algorithm.Algorithm;
 import es.usc.citius.hipster.graph.GraphBuilder;
 import es.usc.citius.hipster.graph.GraphSearchProblem;
 import es.usc.citius.hipster.graph.HipsterDirectedGraph;
 import es.usc.citius.hipster.graph.HipsterGraph;
 import es.usc.citius.hipster.model.problem.SearchProblem;

 public class Find_Shortst_Path extends AppCompatActivity {
      Context context = getApplicationContext();
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_find__shortst__path);
            TextView helloTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    HipsterGraph<String,Double> graph =
            GraphBuilder.<String,Double>create()
                    .connect("A").to("B").withEdge(2d)
                    .connect("A").to("C").withEdge(2d)
                    .connect("A").to("D").withEdge(2d)
                    .connect("B").to("E").withEdge(5d)
                    .connect("B").to("F").withEdge(10d)
                    .connect("B").to("G").withEdge(5d)
                    .connect("B").to("H").withEdge(10d)
                    .connect("C").to("I").withEdge(5d)
                    .connect("C").to("J").withEdge(10d)
                    .connect("C").to("K").withEdge(5d)
                    .connect("K").to("L").withEdge(5d)

                    .createUndirectedGraph();


    SearchProblem p = GraphSearchProblem
            .startingFrom("A")
            .in(graph)
            .takeCostsFromEdges()
            .build();


    //Toast.makeText(context, Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search('L').toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    helloTextView.setText(String.valueOf(Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search('L')));

}
}
```

How can I solve this problem? I am going to find shortest path for shopping mall activities such as find some item and reach to it by using shortest path. If you know any other alternative way, it will help me.

Comment: The problem is not with the library. It is with paramter passed to `Toast.makeText()` method

Comment: @Mandy8055 Can you explain  it buddy ?

Comment: It is expecting a `String` on the second paramter but it is not finding the same

Comment: @Mandy8055 What should i do ?

Comment: try to add `.toString()` method to it.Like:`Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search('L').toString()` and then check it and do let me know!!!

Comment: @Mandy8055 Dear, this time it says - Unchecked call to 'search(S)' as a member of raw type 'es.usc.citius.hipster.algorithm.Algorithm' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler, for example:

  void f(HashMap map) {
    map.put("key", "value");
  }
  
Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details

Comment: Not a problem with that!!!There is just the problem with the implementation of your API!!!!Just check what is the return type of `Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search('L')` method and try to store it in the  variable of same type. Your work is done

Comment: Try to print your result in a `textView`.Like: `textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
textView.setText(String.valueOf(Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search('L')));`

Comment: @Mandy8055 Above solution didn't work nether. I update my question by inducing MainActivity.java

Comment: Thank you @Mandy8055 your are right !! thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I determined,

```
  Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search("L").getOptimalPaths();
```

output is a list when i use

```
 .getOptimalPaths();. // Dijkstra's algorithms out put as shortest path
```

My objective was get only optimal path not the whole output genarated by the

```
  Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search("L")
```

then i inserted that output to "List"

```
  List ab= Hipster.createDijkstra(p).search("L").getOptimalPaths();
  helloTextView.setText(ab.get(0).toString());
```

And i send the output to the TextViwe. It's working fine on Andoid

use this dependency

```
implementation 'es.usc.citius.hipster:hipster-core:1.0.1'
```